Mic in P3 jack not working ubuntu 22.04 in Asus zenbook 14
I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 in Asus laptop UX3405MA-PP810W.
The microphone is not working when I connect the headphone via P3.
Additional information:

USB the microfone works
Internal mic from laptop works

Solutions I already tried:

hdajackretask, override the pin configuration
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf. Add the multiple options related to asus laptops from this website: https://docs.kernel.org/sound/hd-audio/models.html

PS: I'm not very expert on Ubuntu, so let me know if any information is missing

Same problem, but with Linux Mint 22
